# How to call Webservice using API Gateway AWS

Tags: android, api, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I want to integrate webservice using API Gateway, I referred [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-android) and followed all steps carefully but From Step: 7 I have no any idea how to pass the parameter using AWS API Gateway, Anyone can help to solve this? I stuck in it till many days. Please help to solve this.

Comment: Are you talking about the ApiClientFactory.endpoint() call? Have you tried replacing "http://localhost" with your API's endpoint URI: "https://<api-id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com" ?

Comment: Can you post your code and a swagger export of your API definition?  Alternatively, you can PM me your code and the API id and region.

Comment: Yeah, I talking about the ApiClientFactory.endpoint() and I replaced "localhost" with my URI but I have no idea about how to pass Access key, Secret Access Key, and region programmatically.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that how to call API using API Gateway AWS

Comment: I'm new in AWS, I stuck in it! Please guys help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the Access key and Secret Access Key if your API method has Authorization set to AWS_IAM.

It is not recommended to use your Access key and Secret Access Key as credentials from within an Android application since that requires distributing your credentials along with your app, making it easy for people to extract your credentials from the deploy app binary and using them for nefarious purposes.

Many application developers prefer to have the application authenticate via a Cognito identity pool.  This is documented in [step 8 here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-android).

If this doesn't work for you, you should be able to use any of the classes which implement the AWSCredentialsProvider interface.  These are [documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html).  You set the credentials provider on your ApiClientFactory instance using the credentialsProvider method, like so:

```
ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory()
  .endpoint("https://localhost/")
  .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
```

Again, I want to stress that you should never distribute your Access key and Secret Access Key with your application.

Comment: I did it! but In Step 7: // Invoke your parentPath1Get method.
OriginalModel output = client.parentPath1Get(param1,body); what is parentPath1Get(param1,body) method and param,body

Comment: The param and body are just placeholders/examples for whatever you need to pass to your method.  The SDK is generated with the method parameters matching those defined in your API.